# Skydrive API - Limit returned results?

Tags: java, android, cloud, live, windows-live

Currently I'm using `client.getAsync(folder + "/files", liveListener)` to check the contents of a folder for a specific file.  At the moment it works well but if the folder has many files in it (which it is likely to have) then the result returned will be rather large so I was wondering if there was any way to limit this?

Using the Google Drive api I can query for files of a certain mimetype which means the results returned is greatly reduced.

Is there anything like this for the Windows Live api?

The documentation doesn't suggest so..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826531.aspx

Looks like a variety of filtering and selection mechanisms. Not one explicitly for mime-types but it does let you filter on some notion of 'type':

> Get only certain types of items by using the filter parameter in the
>   preceding code and specifying the item type: all (default), photos,
>   videos, audio, folders, or albums. For example, to get only photos,
>   use FOLDER_ID/files?filter=photos.

Also looks like you can sort by a variety of criteria and then select by offset, which would seemingly be very useful for what you discuss above.

Answer (score 1):

Introduce a nontrivial folder structure in your file storage. Folders are a natural filtering mechanism for files.